# Save input Chrome extension

Tags: html, input, output, store, autofill

so I am creating an html where the user has to input data that is going to be stored and then auto pasted (autofill). So I am trying to store it (function at top) and it stores it (seen in the link of the live server) but it wont write it down for a check to see that it works but it don't.

And can you give me a tip how to paste it after ?

PS: Doing this in a popup that's why its so unordered.
And when I normaly open the html in live or as a extension the button appears, but when uploading this html it doesn't.

(ADD)= Searched for errors and saw one when pressing button, recorded it and took a screenshot +[image]

Thank you in advance.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYajl.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dropdown.css">
  </head>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Input</title>
    </head>

  <head>
    <script>
        var 
      function save()
      {
        var first_name = document.getElementById("first name").value;
        var last_name = document.getElementById("last name").value;
        var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
        var street_address = document.getElementById("street address").value;
        var house_number = document.getElementById("house number").value;
        var apartment = document.getElementById("apartment").value;
        var postal_code = document.getElementById("postal code").value;
        var city = document.getElementById("city").value;

        document.write("Data: " + first_name + last_name + email + street_address + house_number +apartment +postal_code + city);
      }
    </script>
  </head>

    <form action="" method="GET">


        <div>
          <label for="first name" >First Name</label>
          <input id="first name" type="first name" name='first name' placeholder="Enter your first name here" required> 
        </div>

        <div>
          <label for="last name">Last Name</label>
          <input id="last name" type="last name" name='last name' placeholder="Enter your last name here" required>
        </div>

        E-Mail
        <div>
          <label for="email"></label>
          <input id="email" type="email" name='email' placeholder="Enter your E-Mail here" required>
        </div>

        <div>
          <label for="street address">Street Address</label>
          <input id="street address" type="street address" name='street address' placeholder="Enter your address here" required>
        </div>

        <div>
          <label for="house number">House Number</label>
          <input id="house number" type="house number " name='house number' placeholder="Enter yout house number here" >
        <div>

        <div>
          <label for="apartment">Apartment (optional)</label>
          <input id="apartment" type="apartment" name='apartment' placeholder="Enter apartment (optional)">
       </div>

        <div>
          <label for="postal code">Postal code</label>
          <input type="postal code" name='postal code' placeholder="Enter your postal code here" required>
        </div>

        City
        <div>
          <label for="city"></label>
          <input id="city" type="city" name='city' placeholder="Enter your city here" required>
        </div>





          <!---Dropdown Country-->
        <body>
          Country
            <div>
            <select name="" id="input" onchange="lel()" class="dropdown">
              <option value="albania">Albania</option>
              <option value="algeria">Algeria</option>
              <option value="andorra">Andorra</option>
              <option value="austria">Austria</option>
              <option value="bahrain">Bahrain</option>
              <option value="bangladesh">Bangladesh</option>
              <option value="belarus">Belarus</option>
              <option value="begium">Belgium</option>
              <option value="bhutan">Bhutan</option>
              <option value="bosnia">Bosnia & Heryegovina</option>
              <option value="brunei">Brunei</option>
              <option value="bulgaria">Bulgaria</option>
              <option value="cambodia">Cambodia</option>
              <option value="canada">Canada</option>
              <option value="china">China</option>
              <option value="croatia">Croatia</option>
              <option value="cyperus">Cyperus</option>
              <option value="czechia">Czechia</option>
              <option value="denmark">Denmark</option>
              <option value="egypt">Egypt</option>
              <option value="estonia">Estonia</option>
              <option value="faroe">Faroe Islands</option>
              <option value="finland">Finland</option>
              <option value="france">France</option>
              <option value="germany">Germany</option>
              <option value="gibraltar">Gibraltar</option>
              <option value="greece">Greece</option>
              <option value="greenland">Greenland</option>
              <option value="hong kong sar china">Hong Kong SAR China</option>
              <option value="hungary">Hungary</option>
              <option value="iceland">Iceland</option>
              <option value="india">India</option>
              <option value="indonesia">Indonesia</option>
              <option value="ireland">Ireland</option>
              <option value="israel">Israel</option>
              <option value="italy">Italy</option>
              <option value="japan">Japan</option>
              <option value="jordan">Jordan</option>
              <option value="kuwait">Kuwait</option>
              <option value="laos">Laos</option>
              <option value="latvia">Latvia</option>
              <option value="lebanon">Lebanon</option>
              <option value="libya">Libya</option>
              <option value="liechtenstein">Liechtenstein</option>
              <option value="lithuania">Lithuania</option>
              <option value="luxembourg">Luxembourg</option>
              <option value="macao sar china">Macao SAR China</option>
              <option value="malaysia">Malaysia</option>
              <option value="malta">Malta</option>
              <option value="mexico">Mexico</option>
              <option value="moldova">Moldova</option>
              <option value="monaco">Monaco</option>
              <option value="montenegro">Montenegro</option>
              <option value="morocco">Morocco</option>
              <option value="myanmar (burma)">Myanmar (Burma(</option>
              <option value="nepal">Nepal</option>
              <option value="netherlands">Netherlands</option>
              <option value="new zealand">New Zealand</option>
              <option value="north macedonia">North Macedonia</option>
              <option value="norway">Norway</option>
              <option value="omanm">Oman</option>
              <option value="parkistan">Parkistan</option>
              <option value="palestinian territories">Palestinian Territories</option>
              <option value="poland">Poland</option>
              <option value="portugal">Portugal</option>
              <option value="qatar">Qatar</option>
              <option value="romania">Romania</option>
              <option value="saudi arabia">Saudi Arabia</option>
              <option value="singapore">Singapore</option>
              <option value="slovakia">Slovakia</option>
              <option value="slovenia">Slovenia</option>
              <option value="south korea">South Korea</option>
              <option value="spain">Spain</option>
              <option value="sri lanka">Sri Lanka</option>
              <option value="sweden">Sweden</option>
              <option value="switzerland">Switzerland</option>
              <option value="syria">Syria</option>
              <option value="taiwan">Taiwan</option>
              <option value="thailand">Thailand</option>
              <option value="timor-leste">Timor-Leste</option>
              <option value="tunisia">Tunisia</option>
              <option value="turkey">Turkey</option>
              <option value="ukraine">Ukraine</option>
              <option value="united arab emirates">United Arab Emirates</option>
              <option value="united kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
              <option value="united states">United States</option>
              <option value="vatican city">Vatican City</option>
              <option value="vietnam">Vietnam</option>
              <option value="yemen">Yemen</option>
            </select>
           </div>
           <!---Dropdown Country-->
           State/Province
           <div>
               <select name="" id="shis" class="dropdowntwo">
                <option value="none" disabled selected value>None</option>
                <optgroup value="united states states"label="--------------United States--------------">
                 <option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
                 <option value="Alaska">Alaska</option>
                 <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
                 <option value="Arizona">Arizona</option>
                 <option value="Arkansas">Arkansas</option>
                 <option value="Arkansas">Arkansas</option>
                 <option value="Colorado">Colorado</option>
                 <option value="Connecticut">Connecticut</option>
                 <option value="Delaware">Delaware</option>
                 <option value="District of Columbia">District of Columbia</option>
                 <option value="Federated States of Micronesia">Federated States of Micronesia</option>
                 <option value="Florida">Florida</option>
                 <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
                 <option value="Guam">Guam</option>
                 <option value="Guam">Guam</option>
                 <option value="Idaho">Idaho</option>
                 <option value="Illinois">Illinois</option>
                 <option value="Indiana">Indiana</option>
                 <option value="Lowa">Lowa</option>
                 <option value="Kansas">Kansas</option>
                 <option value="Kentucky">Kentucky</option>
                 <option value="Luoisiana">Luoisiana</option>
                 <option value="Luoisiana">Luoisiana</option>
                 <option value="Marshall Islands">Marshall Islands</option>
                 <option value="Maryland">Maryland</option>
                 <option value="Massachusetts">Massachusetts</option>
                 <option value="Michigan">Michigan</option>
                 <option value="Minnesota">Minnesota</option>
                 <option value="Mississippi">Mississippi</option>
                 <option value="Missouri">Missouri</option>
                 <option value="Montana">Montana</option>
                 <option value="Nepraska">Nepraska</option>
                 <option value="Nevada">Nevada</option>
                 <option value="New Hampshire">New Hampshire</option>
                 <option value="New Jersey">New Jersey</option>
                 <option value="New Mexico">New Mexico</option>
                 <option value="New York">New York</option>
                 <option value="North Carolina">North Carolina</option>
                 <option value="North Dakato">North Dakato</option>
                 <option value="Northern Mariana Islands">Northern Mariana Islands</option>
                 <option value="Ohio">Ohio</option>
                 <option value="Oklahoma">Oklahoma</option>
                 <option value="Oregon">Oregon</option>
                 <option value="Palau">Palau</option>
                 <option value="Pennsylvania">Pennsylvania</option>
                 <option value="Puerto Rico">Puerto Rico</option>
                 <option value="Rhode Islands">Rhode Islands</option>
                 <option value="South Carolina">South Carolina</option>
                 <option value="South Dakota">South Dakota</option>
                 <option value="Tennessee">Tennessee</option>
                 <option value="Texas">Texas</option>
                 <option value="Utah">Utah</option>
                 <option value="Vermont">Vermont</option>
                 <option value="Virgin Islands">Virgin Islands</option>
                 <option value="Virginia">Virginia</option>
                 <option value="Washington">Washington</option>
                 <option value="West Virginia">West Virginia</option>
                 <option value="Wisconsin">Wisconsin</option>
                 <option value="Wyoming">Wyoming</option>
                 <option value="Armed Forces Americas">Armed Forces Americas</option>
                 <option value="Armed Forces Europe">Armed Forces Europe</option>
                 <option value="Armed Forces Pacific">Armed Forces Pacific</option>
                </optgroup>

                <optgroup value="canada states"label="------------------Canada------------------">
                    <option value="Alberta">Alberta</option>
                    <option value="British Columbia">British Columbia</option>
                    <option value="Manitoba">Manitoba</option>
                    <option value="New Brunswick">New Brunswick</option>
                    <option value="Newfoundland and Labrador">Newfoundland and Labrador</option>
                    <option value="Northwest Territories">Northwest Territories</option>
                    <option value="Nova Scotia">Nova Scotia</option>
                    <option value="Nunavut">Nunavut</option>
                    <option value="Ontario">Ontario</option>
                    <option value="Prince Edward Island">Prince Edward Island</option>
                    <option value="Quebec">Quebec</option>
                    <option value="Saskatchewan">Saskatchewan</option>
                    <option value="Yukon">Yukon</option>
                </optgroup>

               </select>
           </div>
           <p><button class="button" onclick="save()">Save</button></p>















        </body>
      </form>
</html>
```